# Reset reactive form FormControl / AbstractControl inside custom control with CustomValueAccessor

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've a component implementing `CustomValueAccessor` which has `clear()` method inside to reset the value of given `formControlName`. Under the hood there is `<input type="file">`. Setting it as a `@ViewChild` and setting native element value is not reflected to `FormGroup`. Also triggering callback from `registerOnChange(fn: Function) {}` with null is not working.

For now I'm just passing the `formGroup.controls.get('myControl')` as an `@Input()` to the custom control component, resetting it there. But is there a better way to obrain the control inside custom control component? I also used `EventEmitter` to do it outside the component but want rather to have this logic written once in the component.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `FromControl` inside your component and work with it also in a reactive way.

ts file:

```
control = new FormControl();
```

html file:

```
<input type="file" [formControl]="control">
```

Then if you want to reset it, you just call `this.control.reset()` and `propagateChange()` with updated value (probably undefined in your case)

Comment: `propagateChange(null)` is not triggered and handled in the view

Comment: @Szorstki can you create a stackblitz example reproducing your error?